Usage of polyglossia breaks lettrine drop caps
I'm facing an issue with the usage of polyglossia and lettrine packages on the same document.
Setup:

MiKTeK on Windows 10
lettrine 2.60
polyglossia 2.1
Tried with both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX

When I use the alternate language capabilities of plyglossia, the lettrine drop caps have a strange behaviour.
Please consider the code below:
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a5paper,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{portuguese}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ecclesiastic]{latin}

\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

        \begin{hyphenrules}{latin}
        \lettrine{L}{orem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Fusce eu consectetur ante.
        Aliquam tristique dui ac dapibus blandit.
        Cras dignissim, nisl a sodales rhoncus, neque nibh dapibus erat, eget finibus purus elit in erat.
        \end{hyphenrules}

        \bigskip

        \lettrine{L}{orem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Fusce eu consectetur ante.
        Aliquam tristique dui ac dapibus blandit.
        Cras dignissim, nisl a sodales rhoncus, neque nibh dapibus erat, eget finibus purus elit in erat.

\end{document}

This produces the following result:

The desired and expected outcome is the second paragraph. If I use any of the plyglossia commands to use the alternative language capabilities (like \text⟨lang⟩, \textlang{⟨lang⟩}, \begin{lang}, \selectlanguage{⟨lang⟩}, \begin{hyphenrules}{⟨lang⟩}), then I get the first paragraph.
I have no idea how to mitigate this and I'm strongly considering dropping the usage of polyglossia.

\lettrine has to shape a full paragraph, but you are ending the group before the end of the paragraph and so its settings are lost. Use erat.\par\end{hyphenrules}.

That's it! Thank you very much!

You need to end the paragraph before issuing \end{hyphenrules}.
I suggest to define your own environment, because this allows customization without code duplication. Here I used \addvspace to separate the Latin paragraph from the rest.
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a5paper,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\setmainlanguage{portuguese}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ecclesiastic]{latin}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{latinpar}{}{%
  \par
  \addvspace{\topsep}
  \begin{hyphenrules}{latin}%
}{%
  \par\end{hyphenrules}%
  \addvspace{\topsep}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{latinpar}
\lettrine{L}{orem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Fusce eu consectetur ante.
Aliquam tristique dui ac dapibus blandit.
Cras dignissim, nisl a sodales rhoncus, neque nibh dapibus erat,
eget finibus purus elit in erat.
\end{latinpar}

\lettrine{L}{orem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Fusce eu consectetur ante.
Aliquam tristique dui ac dapibus blandit.
Cras dignissim, nisl a sodales rhoncus, neque nibh dapibus erat, 
eget finibus purus elit in erat.

\end{document}


I also suggest loading microtype: compare the output using it with the previous. This is particularly important when lines are narrow.


That works! Nice tip on the custom environment! Thank you!
